Update product metafields in shopify extension
I am trying to create extension and I want to create meta field but what I get as response is:

"Access denied for productUpdate field. Required access:
write_products access scope. Also: The user must have a permission
to update products."

What I am doing is 
`mutation {
              productUpdate (
                input: {
                  id: "`+id+`",
                  metafields: [
                    {
                      namespace: "disclaimer",
                      key: "disclaimer",
                      type: "boolean"
                      value: "false"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ) {
                product {
                  metafields(first: 100) {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        namespace
                        key
                        value
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
           }`

In my toml file i have added scope like this but doesn't work
[[access_scopes]]
scopes = "write_products,write_metaobjects"

How can I grant myself access to write, delete, update and everything about a product ?
